# TestMethod Doesn't Support Web Service Call Out Error For Trigger on delete

Tags: trigger, unit-test, code-coverage, callout, apex-webservice

I have this trigger which deletes the Specific Objects records on delation of a record. I wrote a test class for this but since I am a toootal Noob, I was unable to manage to cover the whole thing and am getting the TestMethod Doesn't Support Web Service Call Out error. This is keeping me from deploying my code and I need to get this done asap so can someone please help me ><

Here is my Trigger:

```
trigger DeleteRelatedNotifications on C_Obj_CustomerTodo__c (before delete) {
List<C_Obj_Notification__c> notiflist  = [SELECT Id from C_Obj_Notification__c where C_Item_RR_CustomerTodo__c IN :Trigger.oldMap.keySet()];
if(notiflist.size() < 10000)
delete notiflist;
}
```

Here is my test class which is getting the web call out error,

```
@isTest 
private class DeleteRelatedNotifsTest {
      @isTest static void DeleteRelatedNotifs() {
      //Create Data for CustomerTODO Objet
      Account TestAccount = new  Account();
      TestAccount.Name = 'CerenTest';
      TestAccount.C_Item_P_MobilePhone__c = '09916930993';

      insert TestAccount;

      C_Obj_CustomerTodo__c TestTodo = new C_Obj_CustomerTodo__c();
      TestTodo.C_Item_RR_Account__c = TestAccount.Id;

      insert TestTodo;

      //After Insert there should be one notification created for the task creation

      // Now, our trigger will fire on After delete record so We Delete the record
      Test.startTest();    // Starts the scope of test
      delete TestTodo;
      Test.stopTest();     // Ends the scope of test

      // Now check if it is giving desired results using system.assert
      // There should be zero notification records that is connected to the TestTodo
      List<C_Obj_Notification__c> NotifList = [SELECT Id, C_Item_RR_CustomerTodo__c FROM
         C_Obj_Notification__c WHERE C_Item_RR_CustomerTodo__c = :TestTodo.id];
      system.assertEquals(0,NotifList.size());
   }



}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code that you showed doesn't have any callouts, so I assume that either your **Account** or **Customer Todo** trigger have a web service callout in it.

In order to write a test class for a class that has a callout, you will need to implement a Mock class. You can read more about it [here](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_callouts_wsdl2apex_testing.htm).